# Installing Windows alongside Ubuntu on last partition

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot

I have ubuntu 12.04 installed on my system.I wish to resize my /home (extended) partition and install Windows 7 in the free space. This would result in Windows being installed on the last partition on my hard disk. I have previously setup dual boot systems, but with Windows on the first partition and recovered grub from the live CD when needed. I want to know if there are any known issues I could face in installing Windows to the last partition.

Answer (score 0):

**Windows (usually) don't install on a HDD with other OS than Windows**
Does your Windows installer have a utility to choose a partition? Some of them don't.
If it does, there's a big chance of recognizing your disc as broken since you have a partition of filesystem other than NTFS, FAT and FAT32.

**But if you're not going to reinstall Windows** (you can simply move it), it should be relatively safe. Well... Safe if you're good at reseting registry and rewriting boot sector. This is how: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=916146
If you're not, Windows recovery disc may save you.